# Karate - Nested JSON object schema validation causes KarateException

Tags: karate

```
Feature: Test Karate schema validation

Scenario: Test nested json objects
 
 * def response = read('tasks.json')
 * def schema = { ab: "##[] string", c: "##[] string" }
 * match response ==
 """
{
      id: '#string',
      name: '#string',
      obj1: '#(schema)' ,
      obj2: '##(schema)' ,
      obj3: '#(schema)' ,
      obj4: '#null' 
      
}
"""
```

*Following is json file used* (**tasks.json**)

```
{
    "id": "ad:p2:53456:4634:yu",
    "name": "name",
    "obj1": {
        "ab": [
            "test"
        ],
        "c": null
    },
    "obj2": null,
    "obj3": {
        "ab": [
            "tester"
        ],
        "c": [
            "t1", "t2"
        ]
    },
    "obj4": null
}
```

Error: com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: javascript evaluation failed: string, ReferenceError: "string" is not defined in  at line number 1

I have tried multiple ways like :
obj1: '#(^schema)',
obj1: '#object schema'

but not able to fix the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `##[] #string` , read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#schema-validation